# Cannot get data from SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-express

[image]

When I try to login to my website, an error occurs. I tried with run the SQL Service too.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Connection string

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS (metro);Initial Catalog=metrodb;Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: Can you please post your **connection string** you're using? The error basically says there's something wrong with that connection string .....

Comment: i have updated my question with the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your connection string, you're trying to connect to a SQL Server **Express** instance which is called `SQLEXPRESS (metro)` - is that *really* the actual name of your instance??

Typically, if you don't change any defaults, it's just `SQLEXPRESS` and thus your connection string should be

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=metrodb;Integrated Security=True
```

You can see what SQL Server instances you have (and what they are called) when you go to `Start > Microsoft SQL Server > SQL Server xxxx > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager` - you'll see something like this:

[image]

You should see at least one `SQL Server (instance name)` service which is started - the name in brackets is your **instance name** (and `MSSQLSERVER` refers to the default, unnamed instance). So what does this show in your case??

Comment: yeah..  I have use the Connection name instead of  server name to connectionString .  Thanks !